# How to call a function method recursively in classes in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

So, I started learning and reading about OOP not so long ago, I've been implementing all the data structures I know using classes and objects just for overall practice and to get comfortable with using OOP in c++.

I'm implementing the tree data structure and I've been wondering how to call a method recursively(I'm aware that I have to pass in an argument) so that when I create an object in main and call a specific method it's written like the following  `a.inorder();` and not `a.inorder(root)` since root is a private attribute.

Is this possible ?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

class tree
{
private:
    node* root;
public:
    tree();
    tree(int val);

    void insert(int val);
    void preorder();
    void postorder();
    void inorder();
    int count();
};

tree::tree() : root { NULL }
{
}
tree::tree(int val)
{
    root = new node;
    root->data = val;
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
}

void tree::insert(int val)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        root = new node;
        root->data = val;
        root->left = root->right = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        node* t = root;
        node* p = NULL;

        while (t)
        {
            p = t;

            if (val > root->data)
                t = root->right;
            else
                t = root->left;
        }

        t = new node;
        t->data = val;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;

        if (p->data > t->data)
            p->left = t;
        else
            p->right = t;
    }
}
void tree::preorder()
{
    if (root)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If a class has a property like `root` then passing it in to a function is redundant, the class already knows what that is. For recursion you can always have a separate `protected` method that does the digging, then use that as you see fit.

Comment: indirection is your friend...
call from that method another [private] method that does the recursion

Comment: "I'm aware that I have to pass in an argument " - when in a class, each (non static) method attribute is automatically passed a 'this' pointer.  The hidden pointer can be sufficient in some recursive efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your design, a `node` refers to itself. Since it is the `node` object that is recursive, you could define the recursive method on `node`:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    void preorder() {
        //...
        left->preorder();
        right->preorder();
    }
};
```

And then, `tree::preorder()` would just dispatch a call to `root->preorder()`.

Answer (score 1):

Write a private static recursive function passing to it the pointer to the root node and call the function from the corresponding public non-static member function.

For example

```
public:
    std::ostream & preorder( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        return preorder( root, os );
    }
    //...

private:
    static std::ostream & preorder( const node *root, std::ostream &os );
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment rather than an actual answer, as it addresses a different issue than you are asking about. However, it is too long for a comment space, that's why I post it here.

I suppose you erroneously refer to `root` in this part

```
        while (t)
        {
            p = t;

            if (val > root->data)
                t = root->right;
            else
                t = root->left;
        }
```

IMHO it should look like this:

```
        while (t)
        {
            p = t;

            if (val > t->data)
                t = t->right;
            else
                t = t->left;
        }
```

Also compare the code to seek a place for insert with a code that makes an actual insertion:

```
        if (p->data > t->data)
            p->left = t;
        else
            p->right = t;
```

You've put a comparison subexpressions in reversed order - when seeking, you test whether the new value is greater than that in an existing node, but when inserting, you test whether the existing value is greater than the new one. If they differ, the code will work OK, because you also swapped `left` and `right` in the 'then' and 'else' branch.
However, if the values appear equal, the execution control will go to 'else' in both places. As a result the testing code may stop at empty `left` pointer, but then a new node would get appended to the `right`, which was not tested for being `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the `tree` class do intrinsic operations on `node`? The `node` class knows best the `node`'s internal structure, so let it initialize itself. This will also help you to stick to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and, indirectly, to the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), as well as the [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    node(int val) : data(val), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}        
};

class tree
{
private:
    node* root;
public:
    tree();
    tree(int val);

    void insert(int val);
};

tree::tree() : root { NULL }
{
}

tree::tree(int val) : root(new node(val))
{
}

void tree::insert(int val)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        root = new node(val);
    }
    else
    {
        node* t = root;
        node* p = NULL;
        
        while (t)
        {
            p = t;
            
            if (val < t->data)
                t = t->left;
            else
                t = t->right;
        }
        
        t = new node(val);
        
        if (t->data < p->data)
            p->left = t;
        else
            p->right = t;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can make `insert` recursive, too.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    node(int val) : data(val), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}        
};

class tree
{
private:
    node* root;
public:
    tree();
    tree(int val);

    void insert(int val);
protected:
    void insertat(node* p, int val);
};

void tree::insert(int val)
{
    if (!root)
        root = new node(val);
    else
        insertat(root, val);
}

void tree::insertat(node* t, int val);
{
    if (val < t->data)
    {
        if (t->left)
            insertat(t->left, val);
        else
            t->left = new node(val);
    }
    else
    {
        if (t->right)
            insertat(t->right, val);
        else
            t->right = new node(val);
    }
}
```